# How to loop through records in "application/ld+json"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, json-ld

I'm trying to create an "[ItemList](https://schema.org/ItemList)" as part of the schema.org structured data markup. For the itemList I can't iterate over the `@posts` to programatically create the list using `:plain` or `:cdata`.

```
- content_for(:header) do
  %script{:type => "application/ld+json"}
    :plain
      {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@graph":
      [
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "ItemList",
          "itemListElement":
          [
            - @posts.each do  |post|
              {
                "@type": "ListItem",
                "position": 1,
                "item":
                  {
                  "@id": "https://example.com/post",
                  "name": "#{post.title}"
                  }
              }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Has anyone had success doing this, or could suggest an alternative to still populate the itemList?

Comment: you can try gem https://github.com/ruby-rdf/json-ld

Comment: What do you mean you "can't iterate over the `@posts`"? Do you get an error? Nothing is output? We need a better example of "can't".

Comment: The ruby isn't executed in the view, I reckon because of the usage of `:plain`. I think your comment below is smart wherein you iterate and store this action in the controller, and access it from the view.

Answer (score 1):

Outside the view, create a regular Ruby hash for your JSON data.

Then, your view would just look like

```
%script{ :type => "application/ld+json" }
  != my_ruby_hash.to_json
```

Comment: Good thinking @claasz

Comment: It seems like converting the hash to JSON should occur in the controller though. A view should only render.